# Placement of figure in two columns text

Tags: floats, two-column, revtex, paper-size

I need to place a 1 column-width figure at the bottom of the first column, but if I use `[b]` like in the following code, the figure is placed at the bottom of the second column...

```latex
\documentclass[%
reprint,
superscriptaddress,
amsmath,amssymb,
aps,
prb,
]{revtex4-2}

\hypersetup{
        colorlinks   = true,
        citecolor    = blue,
        linkcolor    = blue}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{nameref}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amstext}
\usepackage{mathtools} 
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}   
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{placeins}%
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{dblfloatfix}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}

\begin{document} 


\begin{figure}[b]
 \centering
 \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{img.eps}
 \caption{}
 \label{fig:figure}
 \end{figure}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Is this perhaps just a symptom of the document class? And filling an empty page? Perhaps an odd or even page feature? You should try placing the picture on pages with lots of paragraphs. But most importantly, if you are actually supposed to be using that document class for your paper, whatever it produces is most likely how it is required to be for your journal.

Comment: But I forgot to say, you can try other placement commands, you could try `[b!]` `[h]` `[h!]`. The h means place here, and the ! means to try harder to place it where you told it to.

Comment: Converting this to `\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}` yields a figure at the bottom of the first column.  So the problem must be something specific to the `revtex` document class.

Comment: @bob - Actually, all [!] does is ignore the topnumber and bottomnumber.  Most of the time it makes absolutely no difference w.r.t. positioning (unless you have more than 3 top floats or 1 bottom float in the queue).  BTW, a bottom float that is larger than `\bottomfracton\textheight` (which is rather smalll) will not print until the next `\clearpage` or end of document.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so having gotten to a PC and tried out the class, that is a very complete class for very specific needs. If you are not submitting an article to a journal that requests exactly what that class offers, chances are you are going to have a very hard time making any custom formatting changes without a very serious and extensive knowledge in tex and latex.

But to add to my previous conjectures, playing around in the example found here:
https://journals.aps.org/revtex/revtex4-2-tds.zip
Under `\doc\latex\revtex\sample\aps\apssamp.tex` I was able to get figures to appear on the bottom or top of any page using only `[b]` and `[t]`. You can try adding figures to page 3 for a good example, as there are no other conflicting floats that want to land on that page. I could find no correlation to even or odd page numbers so I suspect you are just fighting your other floats.

I cannot tell from your mwe how much you have worked on your project, but you have a lot of packages loaded as well. Particular the `placeins` package could cause issues with this class. I also noticed that you are loading `dblfloatfix` which based on this example, doesnt seem to be nessesary as there is a two column float on page 5 via `\begin{figure*}` emphasis on the `*`. There is a lot of functionality build into this class and its options such as `amsmath` and `amssymb` so you shouldnt need to load those packages separately. This class also a `%floatfix` option in but in this example it is commented out by default so I did not try it. I would recommend trimming what I suspect to be a copy-pasted preamble down to features you specifically need such as `siunitx`.

Comment: I forgot to report on the empty page idea. This class tries to balance a not completely filled page such that the two columns are of equal length (so the last page in the article looks nice). This means that if you typeset an otherwise blank page with only 1 figure, it isnt going to be on the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 1):

What Bob said.

This is not an answer, but more an expanded comment:

Floats are designed to float, for good typographical reasons.

If you absolutely need your image *not* to float anywhere, take it out of the `figure` environment and place it inline. You will need to experiment several times with exactly *where* in the text flow it should go, and you will also need to use the `\captionof{figure}{...}` command from the `capt-of` package to apply the caption and to correctly step the `figure` counter and TOC matters.

[image: inline]

But this is not really practical, because you won't know beforehand what additional typesetting actions the journal will take.

`reprint` option does two-column mode.

MWE

```
\documentclass[%
reprint,
%superscriptaddress,
%amsmath,amssymb,
%aps,
%prb,--
]{revtex4-2}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
        colorlinks   = true,
        citecolor    = blue,
        linkcolor    = blue}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{capt-of}

\begin{document} 
\lipsum[5-7]

%\begin{figure}[b]
{ \centering
 \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image}
 \captionof{figure}{A Caption}
 \label{fig:figure}
 }
% \end{figure}

\lipsum
\end{document}
```

---

RevTex4 is quite a powerful package.

It provides an `endfloats` option and a corresponding `\printfigures` command which (p 63 of the documentation) "determines where the figures are to appear
in a document in which `\floats@sw` is false. If the user invokes the `endfloats`
class option and fails to insert a `\printfigures` command, the figures will be printed
at the end of the document. If the command is given, but floats are not being deferred, it
amounts to a no-op." - which implies the APS likes the figures printing together when they don't float. And, indeed, running with that option, the list of figures is actually called "Figures":

[image: printfigures]